# Conversion failed: on executing stored procedures, string to datetime

Tags: sql-server

```
          --- @param, @1, @2, @3, @orderdate,                   @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @processdate,           @9, @10
exec storedprocedure '01','1','2','3','2017-05-23 18:27:03.290','4','5','6','7',8,'2017-05-23 18:27:03.290','9',10
```

Do anyone knows the right syntax for converting these strings (@orderdate & @processdate) from string to datetime datatype? I'm currently using sql server 2008.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[table] 
            @param  varchar(2)=NULL,
            @1  nvarchar(40)=NULL,
            @2  nvarchar(100)=NULL,
            @3  nvarchar(40)=NULL,
            @ORDERDATE  datetime=NULL,
            @4 decimal=NULL,
            @5 nvarchar(10)=NULL,
            @6 nvarchar(10)=NULL,
            @7  nvarchar(6)=NULL,
            @8  nvarchar(12)=NULL,
            @PROCESSDATE datetime=NULL,
            @9 nvarchar(30)=NULL,
            @10 bit=NULL


BEGIN TRY
    IF @param ='01' 
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [TABLE]
                    ([1], [2], [3], [ORDER_DATE], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [PROCESS_DATE], [9], [10])
            VALUES
                    (@1, @2, @3, @ORDERDATE, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @PROCESSDATE, @9, @10)

        END
```

Error Message

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: The format that you have should be fine.  Show the definition of the stored procedure.

Comment: It might be a `datetime` column and these parameter values are in `datetime2`. It should work if trying with date as `'2017-05-23 18:27:03'`..

Comment: And what is `storedprocedure`? How is it defined?

Comment: Did you have a look into section [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles)?

Comment: Looks like some order mismatch as well, it is better to execute sproc as "Exec StoredProcedure @param = '01', ..."

Comment: @KtX2SkD yes I have

Comment: What are the data types of all the fields in the table? Because if process_date and order_date are both a datetime, then it's not because of those 2 fields.

Comment: `VALUES (@1, @2, @3, CAST(@ORDERDATE AS DATETIME), @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, CAST(@PROCESSDATE AS DATETIME), @9, @10)` helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your code as-is, maybe due to the lack of `AS`, name conflict between procedure and table, something wrong with the `BEGIN/END/TRY` keywords, or the fact that I'm on 2012/2016. **Please** triple-check that it works as-is.

Irregardless, the code can probably be downsized without accidentally influencing the problem. Please try what's below and post back (*it works fine for me*):

```
/*
DROP TABLE [TABLEONE]
DROP PROCEDURE [PROCEDURESEVEN]
*/

CREATE TABLE [TABLEONE] ([1] nvarchar(40), ORDER_DATE datetime, PROCESS_DATE datetime)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURESEVEN] 
    @param  varchar(2)=NULL,
    @1  nvarchar(40)=NULL,
    @ORDERDATE  datetime=NULL,
    @PROCESSDATE datetime=NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [TABLEONE] ([1], [ORDER_DATE], [PROCESS_DATE])
    VALUES (@1, @ORDERDATE, @PROCESSDATE)
END
GO

EXEC [PROCEDURESEVEN] '01', 'DUCK', '2017-05-23 18:27:03.290', '2017-05-23 18:27:03.290'
GO
```

If it works, try *gradually* upsizing from this form, to identify the breaking point.

Comment: Thank you, you were really helpful. I already pin pointed the problem, it is not because of the exec. This really helped me alot. Thanks be to God for someone like you.